# Kinetic energy of a gyroscope toy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes

Why the energy only has rotational part $\frac{1}{2}I_1\omega_1^2+\frac{1}{2}I_2\omega_2^2+\frac{1}{2}I_3\omega_3^2$? The center of mass also moves in general.

Comment: What gyroscope toy?

Answer (score 1):

The formula $T=\frac{1}{2}I_1\omega_1^2+\frac{1}{2}I_2\omega_2^2+\frac{1}{2}I_3\omega_3^2$ is derived from $T=\sum\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. We substitute $\vec{v}=\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}$, and define the inertia tensor $I_{ij}=\sum m\left(r^2\delta_{ij}-r_ir_j\right)$. We can select the coordinates such that $I_{ij}$ vanishes whenever $i\neq j$. Then we arrive at the first formula for kinetic energy.

Note that the above discussion is merely **kinematic**. $\vec{v}=\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}$ holds regardless of the **dynamic** properties of the reference point. Now when we apply this formula, based on dynamic concerns, it holds whenever $T=\sum\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ holds (in which $\vec{v}$ is relative to the reference point). So this formula holds under two circumstances:

- The reference point is stationary. (And if so we do not require it to be the center of mass)
- The reference point is the center of mass of the system and $T$ is the rotational part of the kinetic energy. This is due to the [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(kinetics))

Note that $I$ is always with respect to the reference point. So under the first circumstance, we have a $I$ which is not with respect to the center of mass, thus it is not 'only rotational part'. We can further decompose it into rotational and translational part through the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) for moment of intertia.

Comment: Thanks. So if we choose arbitrary point (non-center of mass, non fixed) it will fail to compute the kinetic energy by adding translational and rotational/or simply rotation right? Another question is how can we compute the angular velocity? Does it connect to principal axis? But when we change the axis then the inertia tensor will change too. Then we'll get another rotational energy?
Also, like in this scenario, if we want to compute the with respect center of mass. Why do I think we still need to add the translational part, but the rotational part is still the one I gave before?

Comment: Then they give different result?

Comment: Well, with respect to an arbitrary point, $T=T_{rot}+T_{trans}$ does not hold. The angular velocity is purely kinematic, it is a vector, whose physical significance doesn't depend on the selection of axes. When we change the axes we will get different components of angular velocity and different components of moment of inertia. The kinetic energy will not change, for angular velocity is a vector and moment of inertia a tensor, and $\omega_iI_{ij}\omega_j$ is a coordinate-system-invariant.

Comment: With respect to the COM, your formula will give the rotational part of the kinetic energy. If the COM is moving and you want to calculate the total kinetic energy, the translation part should be added (this addition only holds with respect to the COM).